# how to generate a random number with a maximum and minimum value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to generate a random number with a minimum and maximum value. Currently I have the following variable that generates numbers between 0-2000. I want to be able to generate a between 500 and 2000. Will need to create local variables to achieve this?

```
random = Math.floor(Math.random()*2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
```

If you need to generate more than one random number you need more than one variable.

Edit: One parentheses was missing in the code example

Comment: Thank you, that was on the tip of my mind, just did think about adding back in the min value

Comment: I had to input another parentheses at the end of min.

Comment: random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);